# Detect dynamic buttons using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have below kind of buttons on my view.Those are generated dynamically through server side code.So my question is I need to write generic jquery click event for do the relevant task of that buttons. (here I have generic method for all buttons on as server code).So how can I detect particular button for write my generic server call ?

**Note :** Common part of the all buttons is **pre-paid-package**

```
 <button id="pre-paid-package-12-day-camp" class="actionButton pre-paid-package-12-day-camp " name="key" value="pre-paid-package-12-day-camp" type="submit">
      Apply 12-Day Camp package
   </button>
<button id="pre-paid-package-20-day-camp" class="actionButton pre-paid-package-20-day-camp " name="key" value="pre-paid-package-20-day-camp" type="submit">
      Apply 20-Day Camp package
   </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [jquery attribute selctor](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("button[id^='pre-paid-package']").on('click', function(){
   // code here
});
```

Here `^` is for starts with

Comment: You sorted out my problem.Thanks for support.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following

**The Html**

```
    <button id="pre-paid-package-12-day-camp" class="actionButton pre-paid-package-12-day-camp " name="key" value="pre-paid-package-12-day-camp" type="submit">Apply 12-Day Camp package</button>
    <button id="pre-paid-package-20-day-camp" class="actionButton pre-paid-package-20-day-camp " name="key" value="pre-paid-package-20-day-camp" type="submit">Apply 20-Day Camp package</button>
```

Th JS

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="pre-paid-package"]', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Johan_fiddle/M9Ykw/4/)

**Edit**
I have updated my answer, as per Anton's suggestion

Comment: I cannot use this.Hence I don't have "dynamicButtons" kind of div when generating buttons dynamically.

Comment: You could bind it to document then or the closest static parentElement @Sampath like this 
`$(document).on('click', '[class^="pre-paid-package"]', function() {`

Comment: @Anton Can't I do that by identifying my common part of the all buttons?I would like to have that kind of solution.

Comment: Identifying your common part? What do you mean, which common part?

Comment: @Anton I have mentioned it on My question. That is "pre-paid-package"

Comment: @Sampath provide the surrounding html? the parent html atleast

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '[class^="pre-paid-package"]', function() {`

this uses the common part @Sampath